# looking for a device or tester to know if car is electrified

Tags: safety, electrical, indicator, electrocution

I'm new here and definitely not an electrical expert - so please forgive any lack of clarity and errors in my terminology or tags.

We live in a rural area and drive a plug-in hybrid electric vehicle which we love. However, recently an electrical-related problem has arisen which is causing us great anxiety. There has been a significant increase in rats throughout our region. They climb into engine compartments and chew on (and can destroy) car wiring.

This can be an expensive nuisance in a conventional car - but in an electric vehicle it can be deadly if they chew through the orange wires (higher voltage – I’ve been told 300V). The mechanic that first noticed evidence of rats under our hood told us that if they damaged those wires, the current could arc, thereby electrifying the car body – and electrocuting anyone who then comes along and touches any metal part of the car.

He warned us to take immediate steps to address the issue, so since then we’ve been employing all the rat deterrents we can muster. My husband has been checking under the hood every day before using the car – very, very cautiously and with great anxiety for both of us, as to do so requires him to touch the car.

My question is this: is there some kind of device that we can use to find out whether the car has been electrified, BEFORE we touch the vehicle? i.e.  something that would (for example) light up, or make a sound, or some other clear indication, if the car was electrified and therefore dangerous? Perhaps something that we leave attached to the car while it’s in the carport, or maybe a portable device that has insulation on one end (the end we would hold) and conduction on the other end (which we would touch against a metal part of the car). Surely there must be some sort of relevant testing device in existence?

FYI: I checked with the car manufacturer and they do not know of such a device (although I expect it would be of great interest to other EV owners as well). I know that we could purchase insulated safety-rated boots and double-layer rubber/leather gloves, like the mechanics who work on electric cars use – but it’s not practical to don heavy gear every time we want to use the car or even just brush by it as we leave the house.

I appreciate any help we can get on this. Thanks very much.

Comment: If your car has rubber tires, how can you be electrocuted? If you have a short, smoke and fire would be good indicators.

Comment: @Sparky256, smoke and fire are the consequences of a catastrophic failure, not indicators of a wiring fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT -

While addressing the larger picture, I did fail to answer the specific question. The device you want is called a voltmeter. The most common version encountered nowadays is the Digital Voltmeter (DVM). To use it , you hold one lead in one hand, making contact with the exposed portion of the probe, then touch the probe of the other lead to whatever point on the vehicle you want to check. The resistance of the meter will limit any current flow through you to safe (and probably undetectable) levels.

In doing this, your body will act as an antenna, and produce a certain about of erratic reading, but a real voltage will produce a jump and a steady reading.

END EDIT

Sorry, but your mechanic is simply wrong - at least in detail.

If you short any part of the wiring to the car body, you will not produce a hazard to someone touching the body. To do this would require two separate shorts: one at one potential to connect to the body, and another at another potential to connect to a dangling wire which contacts the ground. Without two separate connections at different voltages no current can flow and there is no hazard. Classic example - how do birds and squirrels sit and walk on power lines?

Even if the body panels are metal (and hybrids often aren't, in order to save weight), the enamel/paint will act as an excellent insulator, so simply touching the body will not allow current to flow. This condition of insulation does not apply, of course, to touching exposed metal such as trim and door handles. Nonetheless, just touching an exposed metal surface will have no effect unless some other part of you is touching a different metal surface which for some reason is connected to a different exposed wire from the first.

Murphy's Law applies here, of course, so there may be weird situations which will bite you, but they tend indeed to be weird.

Much more likely, for exposed conductors, is simply burning out electronics or literally shorting out the battery with an attendant pyrotechnic display and possible fire. Not to mention killing the battery.

So, rats in the wiring is indeed something to worry about, but "electrocuting anyone who then comes along" is not really on the list.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've written to the mechanic, and await his reply - it's possible we misunderstood what he told us in terms of the danger/concern. In the meantime, your comment is reassuring and has lowered the anxiety level at our house! I am not yet clicking to accept the answer though, because my actual question has still not been answered - whether there's a testing device to indicate whether the car has been electrified. I would still like to know if such a device exists - it seems like there should be something like this available, somewhere!

Comment: @LMacB - See edit.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've been back to the car dealer since I last wrote, and it sounds like we indeed misunderstood what the mechanic told us. Apparently he meant, if, when we open the hood, there's any evidence of rat damage to the high voltage wiring (or a dead rat), do NOT under any circumstances touch it or anything else under the hood - but that the exterior, door handles, hood latch etc. are all safe to touch. So here's my mea culpa to this forum - sorry for my misunderstanding, and thanks for your patience and help. Now I'll return to the photography forum where I more properly belong!